# After a reboot - it's gone (my precious partition :c)

Tags: partitioning, grub2

I left my installation of Ubuntu 22.10 on for about an hour when it had no memory left (I was on a walk :P) and when I "rebooted" with Alt+PrtSc+B it sent me to a grub prompt. After inspection (on my old HDD Ubuntu partition) something seemed to have happened to the boot partition. I can't mount it now. sorry for lack of many details, i don't know what to send though... hopefully you can give helpful feedback!

GNOME Disks
[image]

```
me@the-beast:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/tempie/
[sudo] password for me: 
mount: /mnt/tempie: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
me@the-beast:~$
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it? What tool did you use that gave you that picture?

Comment: It's updated now.

Comment: I found my answer at https://www.linode.com/community/questions/20599/how-do-i-fix-a-bad-magic-number-in-super-block-error... David informed me that you can't just have a link in an answer. Oops.